# background not resizing with window

Tags: css

I am using blogger and recently inserted this cc code in to the advanced section of the template designer to input a background image

```css
body { 
    background: url(http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/9854/ied6.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-color: none;
}
.body-fauxcolumn-outer div {
    background: none !important;
}
```

The problem is that when the browser window is resized the background stays the same but all the widgets/elements on the page resize along with the window.

See [www.ashlylondon.blogspot.com](http://www.ashlylondon.blogspot.com)

I need the background to resize along with the widgets so that they stay in the white area on the background image.

Comment: You could try adding `background-size: cover;` to your body CSS rule

Comment: I tried this Dale and while it did actually resize the background which on reflection is what I asked. Confusingly what I really wanted was the background to 'move' along with the other widgets when the window is resized and stop at the right size (much like it does on this page)

Answer (score 2):

You are relying on background resizing so much that your layout won't work without it. That's not ideal. The typical approach to a situation like this would be:

- Have a background image that covers the entire screen
- Give the `<div>` element that contains the actual content a `background-color: white` property.
- You can still use `background-size` to scale your background image to the screen size, but it no longer is *necessary* for the layout to work.

this woul make sure your content is always readable no matter what; it'll work where `background-size` won't, e.g. in older browsers and some mobile devices.

Comment: I see what you are saying! I am not entirely sure how to add this to every widget but I will give it a pop! thank you

Answer (score 1):

add this to your css

```
body{background-size:100%;}
```

Comment: I tried it on the OP's page and it looks terrible. Not a viable solution (even when disregarding the compatibility issues)

Answer (score 1):

try this

add in body class `background-size:cover;`

http://jsfiddle.net/pyFbF/3/

```
body { 
    background: url(http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/9854/ied6.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-color: none;
    background-size:cover;
}
.body-fauxcolumn-outer div {
    background: none !important;
}
```

Comment: well, I voted you up, but I would like to see the proprietary properties for `cover` as well :) as it is not widely supported

Comment: I tried this and while it does resize the bg image acording with the window size. it doesn't look right...